# JVM garbage collection: What is the difference between "survivor 1" and "survivor 2"?

Tags: java, garbage-collecting

In Oracle's Java Virtual Machine's Garbage Collector, what are the respective roles of "survivor 1" and "survivor 2" ?

Are the objects always moving like: Eden → Survivor 1 → Survivor 2

Or can an object jump directly from Eden to Survivor 2?

Would a "Survivor 3" make no sense, or it could be OK but it was deemed that two are enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survivor1 and Survivor2 are used alternately. Minor GCs scan everything in one survivor space, and move anything that's still needed into the other one, so exactly two are needed.